# Switching CC variable in Makefile based on argument

Tags: gcc, makefile, cross-compiling

I have a C program that I would like to compile for both host and a guest architecture.

Host is i86
Guest is ARM

I tried writing code as follows

```
CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc

all : arm

arm :
    CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc

host :
    CC=gcc

clean :
    rm -rf *.o
    rm bench

$(CC) src/main.c src/cpu/cpu.c src/include/common.c -Isrc -lrt -static -o bench
```

But when i run make arm or make host, I get a missing separator error..
How can I achieve this functionality?

**EDIT**:
I followed the accepted answer, but still want a single target to accomplish my task..
Towards this, I rewrote my Makefile as follows,

```
all : bench

host_helper :
    CC=gcc

arm_helper :
    CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc

arm : arm_helper bench

host : host_helper bench

all : bench

clean :
    @rm -rf *.o
    @rm -f bench

bench : clean
    $(CC) src/main.c src/cpu/cpu.c src/include/common.c -Isrc -lrt -static -o bench
```

This is the output that I obtained while running `make arm`

```
CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
cc src/main.c src/cpu/cpu.c src/include/common.c -Isrc -lrt -static -o bench
```

Why didn't the CC variable change?
Is this because Makefile does a fork for every target and thus the CC variable is lost once the arm_helper target is completed?
Is it possible to achieve the desired goal in this method?

Comment: What is that last line doing in your makefile?  It's not part of a rule...

Comment: Yes, I'm sure..Its complaining about the last line..There is no tab in that line..since my aim is to execute it regardless of the option..
Although, I would eventually like to avoid running the $(CC) when executing `make clean`

Comment: I was hoping to write it similar to a bash script..
How do I get a label to execute another label after a set of commands?

I would like the labels `arm` and `host` to function  as follows:
1) Set the CC variable
2) Run common code which is `$(CC) src/main.c src/cpu/cpu.c src/include/common.c -Isrc -lrt -static -o bench`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line should not be formatted as it is. The purpose of a makefile is to tell the system about inputs, outputs and their dependencies. Thus, you should more appropriately write:

```
bench: src/main.c src/cpu/cpu.c src/include/common.c
    $(CC) $^ -Isrc -lrt -static -o $@
```

And perhaps include `bench` in `all`. The invocation would be either "make all", or "make arm bench".

Labels (actually called targets) are not really "called" from other targets in makefiles. This requires a shift in thinking. Makefiles are not procedural. By their nature, they are dependency trees. Thus, if you want one target to be made whenever another is made, you add it as a dependency; for example:

```
bench: arm src/main.c src/cpu/cpu.c src/include/common.c
    $(CC) src/main.c src/cpu/cpu.c src/include/common.c -Isrc -lrt -static -o $@
```

If I remember my syntax (this may or may not work), you could more cleanly express that as:

```
bench:: arm
bench:: src/main.c src/cpu/cpu.c src/include/common.c
    $(CC) $^ -Isrc -lrt -static -o $@
```

---

To address your new makefile:

First of all, you have `all` written twice. Remove one. Secondly, *do not* make `bench` depend on `clean`. Won't it just delete `bench` after it's linked? Also, your approach to "setting variables based on target" won't work. Please try something like:

```
all: bench-host

bench-host: CC=gcc
bench-arm: CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
bench-host bench-arm: src/main.c src/cpu/cpu.c src/include/common.c
    $(CC) $^ -Isrc -lrt -static -o $@

clean:
    @rm -f *.o
    @rm -f bench-*
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion,
My makefile looks as follows
  
    CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  
  
    all : bench  
  
    arm :  
     CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  
  
    host :  
     CC=gcc  
  
    clean :  
     rm -rf *.o  
     rm bench  
  
    bench :  
     $(CC) src/main.c src/cpu/cpu.c src/include/common.c -Isrc -lrt -static -o bench  
  
Now when I run make arm, it simply displays `CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc`

Comment: If you say "make arm", it does exactly that. It will make the `arm` target, and nothing else. Either type "make" (which implicitly makes `all`), or type "make arm bench".

Comment: This works!
Is it possible to call a label from another label in Makefiles?

Could you also add this to your answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: One last question..
I still desire a single target to accomplish this for me, and thus, I followed your advice and rewrote my Makefile as follows

`all : bench`  
`host_helper :
 CC=gcc`  
  
`arm_helper :
 CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc`
  
`arm : arm_helper bench`  
  
`host : host_helper bench`  

`bench : clean
 $(CC) src/main.c src/cpu/cpu.c src/include/common.c -Isrc -lrt -static -o bench`
  
This displays the following message on make arm  
`CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc`  
`cc src/main.c src/cpu/cpu.c src/include/common.c -Isrc -lrt -static -o bench  `
  
Why didn't CC variable change?

Comment: Newlines are not preserved in these comments. Please post this question by editing your original question.